# How to access etoken through CryptoAPI's?

Tags: cryptography, devicetoken

I am developing an html application where an user has to first login using his digital certificate. After login he has to perform encryption and decryption of data using his digital certificate.
Now in case when the certificate is available in the form of .pfx file then we can just install it and the certificate appears in the container and we can use it during login and during encryption and decryption.
This works fine in case if we have .pfx for our digital certificate.
But now i want to enhance it for etoken's(security token). I dont know much about etoken's. The problem is that how can i use the digital certificate stored in it while login?
Also how should i use the private key stored in it while decryption?

Can anyone please tell me about any tutorials (if any) which will explain the usage of etoken and the CryptoAPI's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the answer to your previous question, Windows CSPs map the certificate from hardware to Windows certificate storage, so this is transparent to you. If you can access the certificate via Windows certificate storage API, then you don't need to care where the certificate is actually located.

Note that you can't transfer a private key to the server, i.e. you would have to use a client-side module (either ActiveX or Java applet) that will perform operations locally. This is not specific to certificates on hardware, but also to certificates which have non-exportable private keys.

Comment: Actually in case of etoken, i dont know what exactly is the problem but it is unable to search for the digital certificate automatically.

Comment: Eugene, i gave a deep thought over your answer and then i understood. I accept your answer and will try to work on client side code. Thanks for you answer.